# How can I keep the hover for the parent ul when hovering the child ul in a dropdown?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have a hover set up on the "ul a" in my dropdown navigation that changes the background color of the a to orange and the text to white.  The problem is, when you hover down to the child menu that opens the orange background on the parent "ul a" goes back to unhovered.

It is the dropdown menu at the top of the page here  http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/simplybusiness/

Comment: show some effort and put together a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)..

Comment: In Chrome the hover state doesn't disappear for me..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way to fix this is to have your hover linked to just the ul and not the a inside it

Comment: Even better: the `li` element that the dropdown is in, instead of the `a`

Comment: I did it this way, just using the li for the hover, but I believe the solution by alnassre would work too.

Answer (score 2):

you should but the drop-down 'ul' inside the 'ul a' to keep the HOVER effect.

```
    <ul>
        <li><a> maintitle
            <ul class="dorp-down-list">
               //------ li li li li
            </ul>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
```

then edit the CSS class from 'ul a'  to 'ul > a'

Answer (score 0):

/* activate 2nd dropdown */

header ul li:hover > ul{visibility: visible;}

/* keep parent a same color */

header ul li:hover > a{color: #000;}